# Change the panel view

Tags: css, html

[image: Like that]I don't know how to explain that, here's a [link](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/f/first-child/) of what I'm trying to do.

The part where there is a text area and when i  click the title, it changes to another text area all being in the same space.
I am not able to change the panel view (java termenology), 
It's really common thing, but I'm new to css, I can't figure out how to do it any help?

Comment: can you elaborate what you want , give a screenshot it will be better !

Comment: i post a picture, thank's for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's called by **tabbed view**.
There is a answer here in StackOverflow:

[how to make tabbed view in html?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1027663/how-to-make-tabbed-view-in-html)

On css-tricks website itself there is a pretty nice tutorial that I almost sure you'll like it:

[CSS3-Only Tabbed Area](https://css-tricks.com/css3-tabs/)

Useful links:

- [14 Tab-Based Interface Techniques](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2007/04/18/14-tab-based-inferface-techniques/)
- [JQueryUI Tabs](https://jqueryui.com/tabs/)
- [CSS- A tabbed interface](http://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/target)
- [Tabbed Interface - Web Experience Toolkit](http://wet-boew.github.io/wet-boew/demos/tabs/tabs-en.html)
- [HTML tab interface using only CSS - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4937371/html-tab-interface-using-only-css)
- [Create a Tabbed Interface Using jQuery (Tuts+)](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/create-a-tabbed-interface-using-jquery--net-314)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this fiddle i made: http://jsfiddle.net/vfaksf7w/1/

```
$('#wrapper').on('click', 'a', function() {
    $('.pannel').hide();
    $('.pannel:nth-of-type('+($(this).index()+1)+')').show();       
});
```

You just have to show/hidewith javascript when you click on proper button :)

Tell me if i didn't undsertand your question correctly.
Hope it helps :)